# Authorization Error while making API using API token

Tags: powershell, authentication, http-headers, authorization, httpwebrequest

I am new to API calls, I am using Powershell for API calls and i have a api token for my application

The application clearly mentions we to create custom http headers to send authenticated requests:

Format is below

```
Authorization: ApiToken 'API_TOKEN_VALUE'
```

When I run the below command in powershell:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://custom.net/users" -H "Authorization: ApiToken avadhohofgsdgdisbgsdhgsfd"
```

I get this error as response

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"errors":[{"code":4010010,"detail":null,"title":"Authentication Failed"}]}
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://custom.net/users
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod]
   , WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodComm
   and
```

Any idea how should i define my http header for successful authentication?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `string` instead of `IDictionary`, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7) for the `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet..,

Specifically the `-Headers` parameter:

```
-Headers <IDictionary>

        Type                    IDictionary
        Position                Named
        ...                     ...
```

So, change your Authorization header to an `Hashtable` (it's a dictionary)

```
$TOKEN_VALUE = 'avadhohofgsdgdisbgsdhgsfd'
$authHeader = @{
'Authorization'= "ApiToken $TOKEN_VALUE"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://custom.net/users" -H $authHeader [...]
```